# I need help connecting an ESP32 to Cumulocity

Tags: iot, esp32, cumulocity

I am very new to IOT. I dont really know much about anything but cant seem to find out anything because everywhere I read there is much assumed knowledge. I have the task of connecting an ESP32 to Cumulocity but dont have much idea where to start. I have seen on a cumulocity video that they have an "agent" for a large amount of devices which is something you can download that will sort out connecting the device to cumulocity for you however they do not have an agent for my ESP32 device which I am trying to connect. It would be much appreciated if someone could head me in the right direction about how I should go about connecting my ESP32 to Cumulocity's platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We followed their sample code

https://cumulocity.com/guides/device-integration/mqtt/

for MQTT, but you can also use their REST API at

https://cumulocity.com/guides/device-integration/rest/

Comment: This shows it running https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XREDTAql3qM